# Is passing pointer to an array as pointer to pointer UB in C?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, implicit-conversion

I have such a code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int **b)
{
    printf("b = %p\n", b); // 0x7ffe76932330
    *b = *b + 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int b[10] = {0};

    printf("b = %p\n", &b[0]); // 0x7ffe76932330
    printf("%d\n", b[0]);      // 0

    func(&b);

    printf("%d\n", b[0]); // 4
    return 0;
}
```

Does this code have UB? To me it seems so, at least due to different types without explicit casting `int (*)[10] != int **`.

Also, what if I have `char b[] = "some string";` instead? The behavior is almost the same... weird.

Comment: I believe passing the array is not UB, but the reassignment of `*b` almost certainly is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing the pointer by itself isn't necessarily undefined behavior, but subsequently using the converted pointer is.

C allows conversions from one object type to another and back, as documented in section 6.2.3.2p7 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a
> different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly
> aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.
> Otherwise, when converted back again, the result shall compare equal
> to the original pointer. When a pointer to an object is converted to a
> pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed
> byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the
> size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the
> object.

So assuming there's no alignment issue (i.e. the array starts on an 8 byte offset on a 64 bit system), just the action of passing a `int (*)[10]` to a function expecting an `int **` is allowed, although most compilers will warn about converting incompatible pointer types.

The undefined behavior happens here:

```
*b = *b + 1;
```

Because you're derferencing an object though an incompatible pointer type (other than a `char *`).  The rules regarding what you're allowed to dereferences are listed in section 6.5p7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a
>   subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

Dereferencing a `int (*)[10]` as a `int **` doesn't meet any of the above criteria, so `*b` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, de-referencing incompatible types are UB, except the rules you mentioned, so if it be `char b[] = "some string"` it's not gonna be UB, right?

Comment: @k1r1t0 It still is, because `char (*)[12]` is not compatible with `int **`.

Comment: sorry, I made unclear example, I meant if it be `func(char **b)` as well

Comment: @k1r1t0 Still UB, because `char (*)[12]` is not compatible with `char **`.

Comment: @chqrlie Only if there's an alignment issue, which I mentioned above as an assumption.

Comment: I would be more explicit about *assuming there's no alignment issue*... The assumption is false on 64-bit systems, which are very common now, so the conversion itself has undefined behavior for these targets, albeit less visibly than `*b`.

Comment: @chqrlie Not so much false as not guaranteed.  If the array in question happens to start on a 8 byte offset, then the condition is met.  Added a note regarding that.

Answer (score 2):

An array is not a pointer, thus a pointer to an array as you pass to `func` with `func(&b)` is **not** a pointer to a pointer.  It is a pointer to an array, an unusual type that is produced when passing an array of arrays to a function (`int b[10][10]` defines an array of arrays of `int`).

Passing `&b` to `func` involves a conversion between pointer types, Something the C Standard allows, but programmers should be careful about: the compiler would issue a warning if configured properly: `-Wall -Werror` is recommended for **gcc** and **clang**.

Regarding the undefined behavior itself: you pass `&b` to `func` expecting an `int **`.  The compiler performs a conversion from the type of `&b`, which is `int(*)[10]` to the type `int **` which might have a different alignment requirement.  Indeed `b` is aligned on the width of `int` (usually 4 bytes), whereas `int *` may require an alignment of 8 bytes, as is the case on most 64-bit systems.

The C23 standard specifies this conversion as having undefined behavior:

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**:
>
> A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

So the Standard describes the very conversion as having **undefined behavior**.

If `int *` and `int` have the same alignment requirements, which is the case for example on 32-bit systems, you don't get undefined behavior when passing `&b` to `func`, but you do when evaluating the expression `*b = *b + 1;` because:

> **6.5 Expressions**
>
> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective
>   type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

Hence dereferencing `b` in `*b = *b + 1` has undefined behavior. For illustration, you can try calling `func(&(b+1))` to check if the undefined behavior is more visible (the program might exit with a bus error).

Also note that `printf` expects a `void *` for `%p`, so `b` and `&b[0]` must be cast as `(void *)` to avoid 2 more instances of undefined behavior.

Comment: Actually, you're right, but the question is not about how to make it work properly, but rather about undefined behavior itself, i.e. what C standard says about it

Comment: Your rewrite *completely* changed the meaning of `*b = *b + 1;`

Comment: @BenVoigt: I updated the answer: I initially missed the language-lawyer nature of the question :)

Comment: @k1r1t0: my bad, I initially missed the language-lawyer nature of the question :)

Answer (score 1):

The type of the expression `&b` is `int ( * )[10]`. There is no implicit conversion from a pointer of the type `int ( * )[10]` to a pointer of the type `int **`. So the compiler should issue a message for this statement

```
func(&b);
```

But even if you will cast the argument expression like:

```
func( (int ** )&b);
```

Nevertheless dereferencing the obtained pointer expression can invoke undefined behavior. That is the expression `&b` used in the function call has the same address value as the address value of the first element of the array.

So within the function the expression `*b` yields the value of the first element (if `sizeof( int * )` is equal to `sizeof( int )` when for example the both are equal to `4`) of the passed array or a combined value of two first elements of the passed array (if `sizeof( int * )` is equal to `2 * sizeof( int )` when for example the size of pointer is equal to `8` and the size of integer equal to `4`).

That is the expression `*b` will not contain a valid address.

Thus this statement:

```
*b = *b + 1;
```

does not make sense. In the provided example as the initial array is zero initialized the expression `*b` can produce a null pointer. You could test the expression within the function for example the following way

```
printf( "*b == NULL is %s\n", *b == NULL ? "true" : "false" );
```

The same problem will take place with the character array:

```
char b[] = "some string";
```

if you will use it the same way.

Instead you could write for example:

```
int b[10] = {0};

int *pb = b;

func( &pb );
```

In this case the expression `*b` within the function will point to the first element of the passed array and this statement:

```
*b = *b + 1;
```

will increment the obtained pointer that will now point to the second element of the array.

Comment: I agree with your analysis, bur C23 6.3.2.3 seems to describe the conversion itself as having undefined behavior.

Comment: The array contents are initialized to zero, but the address of the array is not zero -- `*b` will not be a NULL pointer

Comment: @BenVoigt Address of the array is the expression b within the function. The expression *b reads calues of elements of the array. Did you try the call of printf within the function I showed?

Comment: @BenVoigt Specially for you here is a demonstration program. #include <stdio.h>

void func( int **b )
{
 printf( "*b == NULL is %s\n", *b == NULL ? "true" : "false" );
}


       int main( void )
 {
  int b[10] = { 0 };

  func( ( int ** )&b );
 }
The program output is *b == NULL is true

So before down-voting my answer it would be useful for you to execute the statement with printf shown in my answer.:)

Comment: I thought that your "null pointer" was saying `*b = *b + 1;` would crash because it dereferences a null pointer, first to read and then write. It doesn't. `b` is not a null pointer. Reading or writing `*b` is a strict aliasing violation, and has undefined behavior. Saying it *can produce a null pointer* is a vacuous statement, since UB can produce anything. If not optimized away, it likely will modify a pointer-sized group of bytes inside the array, doing a pointer addition calculation (so likely the integer value of that group of bytes is increased by `sizeof (int)`.  But all bets are off.

Comment: @BenVoigt There is clear written in my answer that the expression *b yields a value or values of the array elements as an address obtaining an invald address and the program demonstrates that. So the expression *b can be a null pointer. What is unclear?